# Redis module is not loading

Tags: node.js, database, redis, redis-server

I am using `redis` as the database for my `nodejs` project.
But if I run the project with `yarn dev` command, it is giving

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Please specify a domain".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

In redis, if I start the server with this command
`redis-server --loadmodule /etc/librejson.so`

it is giving

````
amareshdeshpande@faeko-macbook-pro etc % redis-server --loadmodule /etc/librejson.so
6595:C 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.126 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
6595:C 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.126 * Redis version=7.2.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=6595, just started
6595:C 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.126 * Configuration loaded
6595:M 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.127 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 2560).
6595:M 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.127 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 7.2.0 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                  
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 6595
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           https://redis.io       
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

6595:M 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.128 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because kern.ipc.somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
6595:M 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.128 # Module /etc/librejson.so failed to load: dlopen(/etc/librejson.so, 0x0006): tried: '/etc/librejson.so' (no such file), '/private/etc/librejson.so' (no such file)
6595:M 02 Nov 2023 16:02:26.128 # Can't load module from /etc/librejson.so: server aborting
````